# Sorting an array of strings by string length and number order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, logic, bubble-sort

Does anyone know how to write an implementation of a function that sorts an array in the following way:

Given the following array(randomly ordered):

```json
["1.2", "1.5.3", "1.5", "1.5.2", "1.4", "1.5.3.2", "1", "1.1", "1.5.3.1", "1.2.1", "1.3", "1.5.1", "2", "2.2", "2.1", "3.1", "3", "3.2.1", "3.2.2", "3.2", "3.3", "4"]
```

it should result into ->

```json
["1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.2.1", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.5.1", "1.5.2", "1.5.3", "1.5.3.1", "1.5.3.2", "2", "2.1", "2.2", "3", "3.1", "3.2", "3.2.1", "3.2.2", "3.3", "4"]
```

I'm currently trying to do it in JavaScript with .sort(), and not really succeeding. Logic in any language would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`.sort` actually works fine just by itself here.

```js
const array = ["1.2", "1.5.3", "1.5", "1.5.2", "1.4", "1.5.3.2", "1", "1.1", "1.5.3.1", "1.2.1", "1.3", "1.5.1", "2", "2.2", "2.1", "3.1", "3", "3.2.1", "3.2.2", "3.2", "3.3", "4"]

console.log(
  array.sort()
)
```

Comment: add `"11.2"` as value

Answer (score -1):

```
const arr = ["1.2", "1.5.3", "1.5", "1.5.2", "1.4", "1.5.3.2", "1", "1.1", "1.5.3.1", "1.2.1", "1.3", "1.5.1", "2", "2.2", "2.1", "3.1", "3", "3.2.1", "3.2.2", "3.2", "3.3", "4"];
arr.sort();
```

the result is =

```
["1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.2.1", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.5.1", "1.5.2", "1.5.3", "1.5.3.1", "1.5.3.2", "2", "2.1", "2.2", "3", "3.1", "3.2", "3.2.1", "3.2.2", "3.3", "4"]
```